# AdS$_4$ and $\mathbb{H}^4$: What is the difference between them?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, topology, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

This figure ([source](http://www.sternwarte-luebeck.de/download/forschung/Hyperbolic_space.pdf)) shows the embedding of 4D hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^4$ and 4D de Sitter space dS$_4$ in 5D Minkowski space $\mathbb{M}^5$.  $\mathbb{H}^4$ is a hyperboloid of two sheets and dS$_4$ is a hyperboloid of one sheet.  However, I also understand that 4D anti-de Sitter space AdS$_4$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{M}_5$, and that it is also hyperbolic but simply connected everywhere.  I want to know why the author calls the figure on the right de Sitter space but he calls the figure on the left hyperbolic space rather than anti-de Sitter space.

Is AdS$_4$ just one of the $\mathbb{H}^4$ hyperboloids?  Do the two possible hyperbolic embeddings correspond to the $\{\mp\pm\pm\pm\}$ metric signature freedom?  Does $\mathbb{H}^4$ have a Lorentzian signature or is it just the Euclidean version of AdS$_4$?  If so, how can I reconcile the simply connected property of AdS$_4$ with the disconnected property of $\mathbb{H}^4$?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\text{AdS}_n$ is a sphere of timelike radius in a space of *two* timelike and $n-1$ spacelike dimensions.* $\text{AdS}_n$ itself has one timelike dimension.

For comparison:

$\mathbb H^n$ is a sphere of timelike radius in a space of one timelike and $n$ spacelike dimensions,** and has zero timelike dimensions itself;

$\text{dS}_n$ is a sphere of spacelike radius in a space of one timelike and $n$ spacelike dimensions, and has one timelike dimension itself.

---

* Actually, it's usually taken to be the universal cover of that sphere, since otherwise it's periodic in time, i.e., has closed causal loops.

** Usually with opposite points identified, so that there's only one sheet.

Comment: Thank you.  Could you please make a similar statement about de Sitter space: "dS$_n$ is a sphere of ???? radius in a space of ????"  Thanks!

Comment: @hodopsmith I already did...

Comment: I somehow looked over that when I skipped to your asterisks.  Oops!  Thanks!  This is actually a great description for what I'm working on and I am going to paraphrase you in my paper.

Comment: @benrg, I am just curious. What are Ricci scalar curvatures for this both spacetimes?

Comment: @JanGogolin The Ricci scalar is some small constant times the Gaussian curvature. In terms of the cosmological constant the Gaussian curvature is $Λ/3$ if I'm remembering right. It might also be taken to be $\pm1$ (i.e. a sphere of radius $1$).

Comment: @benrg, that small constant is exact what I am interested in. Recently, I have posted a question regarding scalar curvature for some special (simple) metric but could not get a satisfactory answer. Would you mind to take a look, please? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4357630/1003573